# Can I make http post request from mysql phpmyadmin?

Tags: mysql, http-post

I have an app that uses mysql and php, and I change the state of my data by events from mysql, and I want to make notifications to clients the moment the data state changes.

I know cron jobs can work but with a delay, is there a way mysql can make http post request the moment the data changes.

I tried to use curl from mysql procedure but it fails while execute

```
1305 - FUNCTION my_db.curl_init does not exist
```

the full procedure code is:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE send_notifications()
BEGIN

  -- Set variables
  SET @url = 'url/sendnotifications';
  SET @data = '{"key":"data value"}';

  -- Build the request
  SET @ch = curl_init();
  CALL curl_setopt(@ch, CURLOPT_URL, @url);
  CALL curl_setopt(@ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
  CALL curl_setopt(@ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, @data);
  CALL curl_setopt(@ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  CALL curl_setopt(@ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Authorization: Bearer xxxx'
  ));

  -- Execute the request
  SET @response = curl_exec(@ch);
  SET @error = curl_error(@ch);
  SET @httpcode = curl_getinfo(@ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

  -- Close the request
  CALL curl_close(@ch);

  -- Do something with the response, such as logging it
  IF @httpcode = 200 THEN
    SELECT @response;
  ELSE
    SELECT @error, @httpcode;
  END IF;

END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

I am planning to call a job function that can be executed asynchronously in background without putting load in mysql.